# Upgrading Indy on Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe, indy10

I've been struggling to upgrade Indy on Delphi XE. I followed the instructions on the link below :

http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.en.aspx

Here what i did :

1 - Removed the Indy packages from the IDE

2 - Deleted all Id*.dcu files on the folder

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0

3 - Run the script

> Fullc_XE.bat

4 - When i try to add the dclIndyCore and dclIndyProtocols on the IDE's Component > Install packages, i get the error below :

> The procedure entry point @testbpl_common@initialization$qqrv could
>   not be located in the dynamic library c:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD
>   Studio\8.0\Bpl\dclIndyCore150.bpl”
>
> Can't load package c:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD
>   Studio\8.0\Bpl\dclIndyCore150.bpl. The specified procedure could not
>   be found.

What am i missing here ? Please help.

Thanks !

Comment: You didn't clean up all of the old version. Deleting the DCU files isn't enough. You also need to delete BPL, BPI, and other files. (Basically, scan your entire hard drive and delete or move everything that starts with `dclIn* or `Id` in a location that could be related to Delphi.)

Comment: @KenWhite This did the trick, thank you !

Comment: @KenWhite yes, and that is stated as much in Indy's install instructions

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, I know. Apparently, the poster didn't. :-)